# Moving code from jquery to angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following code block in jQuery which I need to convert it into angularjs

**JS Code**

```
command: [
          {
             name: "Delete",
             text: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span>",
             click: function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             //add a click event listener on the delete button
             var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row for deletion
             var data = this.dataItem(tr); //get the row data so it can be referred later
             wnd.content(confirmationWindowTemplate(data)); //send the row data object to the template and render it
             wnd.open().center();
             wnd.title("Delete Prospect");

             $("#yesButton").click(function (e) {
             alert("hi")
            })

            //$("#noButton").click(function (e) {                     
             $scope.noButton = function() {
              alert("hi!");
              }

            },
            ]
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-blue" id="yesButton">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="noButton()"> No</button>
 </div>
```

I have not posted the entire code as it would be too lengthy. I want to convert this jquery code into angularjs. As you can see I am trying to call Yes and No function with jQuery and Angularjs respectively. When I click on yes, I see an alert message "hi" but I don't get an alert message when I click on no.

I am sorry if this question provides insufficient details. I am stuck on this from past 2 days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check to see if noButton() is in scope

Comment: it is in the scope of the controller.

Comment: Check for errors in your debug console window

Answer (score 0):

How/where your code `$scope.noButton = function() { alert("hi!"); }`

is placed? as per my angularjs knowledge, you required controller in your HTML code and then you can set button with `ng-click` inside that controller, which will finally bind function in your angular controller file code.

**Ref -** http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/introduction/responding-to-click-events-using-controllers.html

and here your yes button code `$("#yesButton").click(function (e) { alert("hi") })` is working with jQuery so its working correctly